# How does the Lipshitz norm of bounded and permutation invariant functions depend on the number of arguments?

Tags: lipschitz-functions, symmetric-functions

Take a Lipshitz function on a compact subset of $R^N$ where we want to scale up $N$.  If we know that (1) the functions are invariant to permutations (2) that there is a bound that is independent of the number of arguments; and (3) there are some sorts of bounds on the curvature (not sure the exact condition).  Can we make any claims on how the Lipshitz coefficient scales with the number of arguments?

**To try to formalize this (which might be the wrong direction):**

Take a sequence of function $f_N : [0,1]^N \to R$.  Denote an element as $X \in [0,1]^N$. The key structure is:

- The function $f_N$ is invariant to permutations.  That is, for any permutation matrix $P_N \in R^{N \times N}$, $f_N(P_N X) = f_N(X)$.
- Some sort of bound on the curvature that is independent of $N$.  Maybe on the hessian?
- The function $f_N$ is Lipshitz.  Denote its Lipshitz norm as $\|f_N\|_{Lip}$
- There is a bound on the function independent of $N$.  That is
  $\max_{X \in [0,1]^N} f_N(X) \leq K$ for all $N$, for some $K < \infty$.

Given this structure (i.e. invariant to permutations and bounded independent of $N$), can we make any claims on the maximum dependence of the Lipshitz norm?  In particular, I would like to claim that there exists a constant $C$ such that $$\|f_N\|_{Lip} \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{N}}$$

Or something like that.  If this is true, how can it be proved?  What is the precise condition bounding the curvature that we would need to add to eliminate counterfactuals (such as the one below)?

---

To have some examples in your mind:

1. A good example of a function fulfilling the criteria is the mean function defined on any compact set.
   $$
   f_N(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n
   $$
   In that case, we know that the $\|f_N\|_{Lip} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$.  This is clearly symmetric and fulfills the boundedness criteria since for any N, $\max_{X \in [0,1]^N} f_N(X) = 1$.
2. Alternatively, while something like $f_N(X) = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ is Lipshitz and symmetric, $\max_{X \in [0,1]^N} f_N(X) = N$ which is symmetric but not bounded independent of $N$, and hence wouldn't fulfill the criteria I am looking for.
3. Similarly, while $f_N(X) = x_1$ is Lipshitz and bounded independently of $N$, it is not invariant to permutations.  So I think symmetry is required here.
4. The example $f_N(X) = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^N$ is Lipshitz and symmetric, $\max_{X \in [0,1]^N} f_N(X) = 1$ (since it is on the boundary). And yet the Lipshitz constant blows up.  However, note that this function has curvature that explodes as $N$ increases.

This is useful for bounding the concentration of measure for high-dimensional probability with symmetric functions---which will themselves come out of neural network approximations.

Comment: For your first example, the average of the coordinates, you actually have $\|f_N\|_{Lip}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$. Note that $f_N(1,\dots,1)=1$ and $f_N(0)=0$, while the length of the diagonal is $\sqrt{N}$. You can also compute that $\|\nabla f_N\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, which is equivalent to the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, let me fix that up.  Thank you.  Decreasing at that rate is totally fine as well.  The key is that it converges to zero with $N$.

Comment: Consider $f_N(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^p$. The bound is always $K=1$ for all $p$, but as $p\to \infty$ the Lipschitz norm of $f_N$ blows up.

Comment: @Jeff  Thanks.  I fixed the $\sqrt{N}$ thing.  Take a fixed, but large, $p$.  Are you saying that if you do that in your example the $f_N$ is not bounded by anything related to $N$?  Maybe there is another criteria that I need to add to the "proposition" I might have in mind?

Comment: @Jeff I think you are saying that it is $f_N(X) = 1/N \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^{p(N)}$ where $p(N) \to \infty$  for example $p(N) = N$?  Lets say it is $f_N(X) = 1/N \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^N$  If so, then yes the lipshitz blows up as $N \to infty$ and is bounded by $1$ since it is exaclty on the unit hypercube.  We are adding in an additional criteria that things are weakly concave, which eliminates this example.  Does that help?

Comment: Convexity has nothing to do with it, you can take $f_N(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^{1/p}$ and get the same thing. You can't control the Lipschitz norm of a function by it's supremum norm (and the permutation symmetry is not helpful for this).

Comment: @Jeff I see what you are saying.  What sort of things could we add to eliminate that kind of crazyness?  Just to be clear, this only happens if $p(N)$ is a function of $N$.  Otherwise there isn't any issue as far as I can tell?  It seems to me that the problem is only coming about because the curvature is increasing as $N$ is increasing?  Any other ideas?  Bounding the hessian by an $N$ independent constant for example?

Comment: Do you know about Sobolev embeddings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality

Comment: Not really, but looks relevant.  What do you have in mind with it?

Comment: I think you are looking for a type of Sobolev embedding. They allow you to control $L^p$ or $L^\infty$ norms of a function or its derivative in various ways. If you are not familiar with Sobolev inequalities, then I would suggest to review these and try to rephrase your question. It is also not clear to me why you are ok assuming a Hessian bound (this is stronger than Lipschitz, so why not just assume the Lipschitz bound)?

Comment: @Jeff  Ah good point on the hessian bound.  I will try to take a look at the sobolev stuff and see if it can work.  Just to make sure I understand:  the only way to eliminate your counter-example (e.g. $f_N(X) = 1/N \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^N$) would be that we say all of the functions need to be in a sobolev space with an infinite number of weak derivatives?  Or am I missing something?  If so, would that be reasonable or far too strong (i.e. add the assumption that all $f_N$ are all $W^{\infty, p}$ for whatever norm $p$ we need?

Comment: Not an infinite number of weak derivative, just a few, but the number depends on dimension in the Sobolev inequalities.